# Hang up call after it rings certain amount of times

Tags: java, android, telephonymanager

so i guess title is pretty self explanatory, i have an app where i need to make a phone call and after it rings certain amount of times (let's say 2-3), i need to hang up to leave a missed call.

With some help from already created topics, i can make a phone call and hang up, but only after certain amount of seconds, not ring tones. Problem with seconds timer is, you cannot be certain if ringing already started.

Is there even a way in API to let me know when the phone rings?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Ringing State Out Going Calls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19509292/ringing-state-out-going-calls)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This SO article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19509292/ringing-state-out-going-calls) deals with the exact same issue.
As of now there is no public API that can detect the ringing on the other side of the call.

Comment: I think that this should be posted as a comment since the statement you made can be found in the article.

Comment: While dealing with a similar problem, I found out that currently no API supports this feature. I'm sharing my own conlusion to this problem as an answer to his question. So no, this should not be a comment.

Comment: It might be my mistake, but this was my opinion since your conclusion and the one from article are really really similar. Also, in case of duplicated questions is recommended to mark them as duplicate, not to answer.

Comment: Jeff thinks [otherwise](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/11/16/dr-strangedupe-or-how-i-learned-to-stop-worrying-and-love-duplication/).

Comment: Without some context, I don't know what you are referring to. Check this https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10841/how-should-duplicate-questions-be-handled, and you'll see that you shouldn't answer to duplicated questions.

Comment: It looks that the opinions are devided, but given the fact that your answer doesn't add any new information compared with the one provided, I believe that should be a comment in the end.

Comment: Thank you for your opinion. But my answer clearly states that there is currently **no public API available to solve OP's problem**. Which is the direct answer to OP's question: *Is there even a way in API to let me know when the phone rings?*.

Comment: Skipping right to the answer, thank you very much for confirming what i already suspected.